# how to create a custom helper module on Parse.com CloudCode for using with then() promise? TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parsing, module, promise

I'm new to Parse.com CloudCode and Node.js

I'm trying to find a way to create a helper module with some querys and other common codes I may need to use over and over again in my app.

How can I create a module with helper methods which are not synchronous?

How can I make it work with the promises?  http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/

Here is my intention.... I'm not sure what is the correct approach for this

I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

```
exports.getMyObjects = function (myParam, status) {

var MyObject = Parse.Object.extend("MyObject");

var query = new Parse.Query(MyObject);

query.get(myParam).then(function(myObjects){

status.success(myObjects);

},function(error){

 status.error(error);
});

};
```

---

```
//Here on another file I'm trying to use the module

var helper = require('cloud/helper.js');

helper.getMyObjects('sdfsd43').then(function(myObjects){

 //Objects found!
},function(error){

//Error
});

// I'm getting thes error from parse: TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to fix it by changing the parse version in the global.json

"global": {

```
"parseVersion": "1.2.7"
```

}